# FFmpeg Crossfade and loop audio file with itself multiple times

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I really need to loop batch of audio (7mins each) in filter_complex with acrossfade. I tried the following code, but it works strange.
Because if i use this code - i got 2 repeats of a single file. File becomes a bit cropped in the end.

```
ffmpeg -i 0.mp3 -vn -filter_complex "[0][0]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri" out2.mp3
```

But if i use this code i got 3 repeats (why?) And ending of a file is a bit cropped.

```
ffmpeg -i 0.mp3 -vn -filter_complex "[0][0]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a01],
 [0][0]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a02],[a01][a02]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri" out2.mp3
```

Can i use this method?

```
    ffmpeg -i 0.mp3 -vn -filter_complex "[0][0]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a01],
 [0][0]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a02],
 [0][0]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a03],
 [0][0]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a04],
 [0][0]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a05],
 [0][0]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a06],
 [0][0]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a07],
 [0][0]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a08],
 [0][0]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a09],
 [0][0]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a10],

 [a10][a09]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a11],
 [a08][a07]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a12],
 [a06][a05]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a13],
 [a04][a03]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a14],
 [a02][a01]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a15],

 [a15][a14]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a21],
 [a13][a12]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a22],

 [a11][a22]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a31],
 [a21][a31]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri" out2.mp3
```

But i think it's scary and there is a way to make it simpler...

Comment: Are there blank spaces in the input files? When rip a file I try and edit it, removing any blank areas in the beginning and ending so when I play the song it has no empty (blank) area, just hops to the next song. Also if I burn it the software places 2 seconds between the two anyway. That way there isn't 4-6 seconds of blank between the music.

Comment: There is only one number in a file name

Comment: Is it because when you crossfade, it moves the audio over to actually crossfade, leaving a gap of blank space?